# How to get data from one page (databound) to another page's textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Suppose I have two .aspx pages and a connection the the sql server database engine.

The first page, let's call it playground.aspx, I'm having a set of databound which using the stored procedure for SELECT function (using dataset for it).

Now in the second page, let's call it link.aspx, there are two textbox, suppose there are multiple data in the playground.aspx page and I want to retrieve Entity Code and Username data (from the playground.aspx's databound) and show it in the link.aspx's textbox.

How can I do that?
I was told to create some function, but I never dealt with a databound before, only with TextBox and Label, it really confused me.

Any help's appreciated, thank you.

> EDIT (Here's the databound code)

```
 <asp:Panel ID="PanelDGV" runat="server" Height="100%" ScrollBars="None" Width="100%">
                                        <asp:GridView ID="DGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
                                            AllowPaging="true" PageSize="2" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="EntityCode" HeaderText="Entity Code" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Username" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DivCode" HeaderText="Div Code" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupCode" HeaderText="Group Code" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy" HeaderText="Created By" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedOn" HeaderText="Created On" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedBy" HeaderText="Modified By" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedOn" HeaderText="Modified On" />
                                                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="../Support/Image/Edit.png" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                                    CommandName="CmdEdit" HeaderText="Edit">
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                                </asp:ButtonField>
                                            </Columns>
                                            <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
                                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: What do you mean by databound? Could you show some code?

Comment: I've edited it, if there's anything else please let me know, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem, here's the code

For link.vb

```
Public Function F01_sysUser_Select(ByVal EntityCode As String, ByVal Username As String) As ProcessResult
    Try
        Dim SqlCmd As New SqlCommand()
        SqlCmd.Connection = New SqlConnection(CF.CfgConnectionString)
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = CF.CfgCommandTimeout
        SqlCmd.CommandText = "sysUser_SelectByID"
        SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@EntityCode", SqlDbType.VarChar) : SqlCmd.Parameters(0).Value = EntityCode

        SqlCmd.Connection.Open()

        Dim Dr As SqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        F01_Dt_sysUser.Clear()
        F01_Dt_sysUser.Load(Dr)

        If F01_Dt_sysUser.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dr.Close()
            Dr = Nothing
            SqlCmd.Dispose()
            Return ProcessResult.SuccessWithResult
        Else
            Dr.Close()
            Dr = Nothing
            SqlCmd.Dispose()
            Return ProcessResult.SuccessWithNoResult
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        InsertErrorLog("PlaygroundLink.F01_sysUser_Select", ex.Message)
        ExMessage = ex.Message
        Return ProcessResult.Failed
    End Try

End Function
```

and in the link.aspx.vb:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim QSEntityCode As String
    Dim QSUserName As String
    QSEntityCode = Request.QueryString("QSEC").ToString
    QSUserName = Request.QueryString("QSUN").ToString

    Dim Bl As New PlaygroundLink
    If Bl.F01_sysUser_Select(QSEntityCode, QSUserName) = CF.ProcessResult.SuccessWithResult Then
        TbEntityCode.Text = QSEntityCode
        TbUsername.Text = QSUserName
    Else
        ' LblMessage.Text = Bl.ExMessage
    End If
End Sub
```

lastly in playground.aspx.vb:

```
Private Sub DGV_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles DGV.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "CmdEdit" Then
        Dim QSEntityCode As String
        Dim QSUserName As String
        Dim idx As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = DGV.Rows(idx)
        QSEntityCode = row.Cells(0).Text
        QSUserName = row.Cells(1).Text
        Response.Redirect(RR.PlaygroundLink & "?QSEC=" & QSEntityCode & "&QSUN=" & QSUserName)
    End If
End Sub
```

After that, I get what I want, displaying the result in the link.aspx textbox, cheers! :)